# Html element is not vertically centered with flex center

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

Thats my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/atav8vzz/4/

Why is the html element with class "vertical-align" not vertically centered?

```
<div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div style="background:green;" class="col-xs-4">             
              <h3 class="text-center">Type 1</h3>            

            </div>

            <div style="background:red;" class="col-xs-4">             
              <h3 class="text-center vertical-align">Type 2</h3> 

            </div>

            <div style="background:blue;" class="col-xs-4">            
                <h3 class="text-center">Type 3</h3>            

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

.vertical-align {
        display: ms-flex;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
```

Comment: You have `margin-top: 20px` and `margin-bottom: 10px` on your `h3`. Perhaps coming from bootstrap. This will prevent middle alignment anyway. Moreover, why are you using flex on your `h3` anyway? Where are the flex children? What will it flex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it depends what you're trying to achieve here. `align-items` does so vertically. Where as `justify-content` does so horizontally.

See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/bxsfb50n/). I have given the `<h3>` height, to illustrate that it is centred vertically.

Answer (score 3):

Just add **justify-content: center;** to your code:

```
.vertical-align {
    display: ms-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;  
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this just center align the text?

Comment: He had asked for vertical alignment, not horizontal in the question.